# Ruby on rails: array at initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working with rails 5.1.2 and ruby 2.2.6

I have the following classes:

```
class Idea < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: false
  has_many :discussions
end

class Discussion < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  belongs_to :idea

  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end
```

At `idea` creation, I'd like to add a default `discussion` in the attribute `discussions`. As I'm a newbie at ruby and rails, I don't know which is the best approach to do this. Here is what I tried unsuccessfully.

In the idea controller, I tried to create the default `discussion` at the `idea` creation, as follows:

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController

  def create
    discussion = Discussion.new "Main thread"
    @idea = Idea.new(idea_params)
    @idea.discussions << discussion
    @idea.save
    redirect_to ideas_path
  end

  private
    def idea_params
      params.require(:idea).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

This drives me to an error in the controller:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

on the line

```
@idea.discussions << discussion
```

I think this is due to an uninitialized `discussions` array in my `idea`. However, the guide states that any class that has the declaration `has_many` would inherit the method `<<`, as stated in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference). But maybe this is only true after the idea has been saved at least one time?

I tried manually initialize the array in my controller.

```
@idea.discussions = []
```

This helps removing the error, but I'm surprised this is not done automatically. Furthermore, the `discussion` is not saved in database. I tried adding the declaration `autosave` in Idea class, with no effect:

```
has_many :discussions, autosave: true
```

I'm a little bit lost. At the end, I'd just like to add a `discussion` in an `idea` between its creation and save, and persist it. What is the best approach?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Discussion` is already an ActiveRecord object, so you don't need the `initialize` method. Simply calling `Discussion.new` should work out of the box.

To build a default `Discussion` when creating an `Idea` just do this:
`@idea.build_discussion` . This is will instantiate a new `Discussion` association on your `Idea` model. When you save `Idea`, it will automatically save the `Discussion` object as well and automatically associate it to that `Idea`.

Edit: To simplify the answer, here's the code:

```
def create
  @idea = Idea.new
  @idea.build_discussion(title: 'Main Thread')

  if @idea.save
    redirect_to ideas_path
  else
    redirect_to :new
  end
end
```

Edit 2: And because you build the `Discussion` through `Idea`, you need to add this to your `IdeaController` `strong_params`:

```
def idea_params
  params.require(:idea).permit(
    ...
    discussion_attributes: [
      :id,
      :title,
      ..
    ]
  )
end
```

Edit 3: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to your association type. Update to this:

```
def create
  @idea = Idea.new
  @idea.discussions.new(title: 'Main Thread')

  if @idea.save
    redirect_to ideas_path
  else
    redirect_to :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Now, I'm facing another issue: **undefined method `build_discussion' for #<Idea:0x00000011128bb0>**.

Comment: You may also need to add `accept_nested_attributes_for :idea` in your Discussion model. See https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to your association. See my updated answer.
@StephanePaquet indeed, you are right!

Comment: @Vlad: I haven't seen this **@idea.discussions.new** in the rails guide, but it does the job! Other point, you told I don't need to define **initialize** in a Rails context. Could you explain or give me any pointer to understand why? Thanks.

Comment: @StephanePaquet I'll take a look at this article. It seems not to be useful in my particular case, but probably in a lot of future cases

Comment: Because behind the scenes, Rails already does that initialization for you. That's why you can call .new on any Model in your app, because it's inherited from ActiveRecord::Base. Same goes for .create, .update, .edit and so on. That's the beauty of Rails, it'll do most of the tedious tasks for you already. As an experiment, if you want, remove the < ActiveRecord::Base inheritance and you'll see that new, create and many other useful features are removed from your model.

Answer (score 3):

First off, don't override `initialize` in an ActiveRecord model unless you know what you're doing. Your object already has an `initialize` method defined, you just can't see it because it's inherited. If you override without accepting the right set of parameters and calling `super` you will introduce bugs.

ActiveRecord gives you an easy hash syntax for setting attributes at initialize already. You can do `Discussion.new(title: 'Title')` right out of the box.

If you always want your `ideas` to be created with a default `discussion` you can move this down to the model in a `before_create` [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

```
class Idea < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: false
  has_many :discussions
  before_create :build_default_discussion

  private

  def build_default_discussion
    discussions.build(title: 'Main Thread')
  end
end
```

Here you're calling the private method `build_default_discussion` before every new `idea` is persisted. This will happen automatically when you create a new `Idea` either with `Idea.new.save` or `Idea.create` or any other proxy method that creates a new `Idea`, anywhere in your application.

Comment: Very good approach if you want a new Discussion created with every Idea. This way is also very good for when you create a new Idea using a console or a task.

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing it in the controller, and your proposition fits still better my hopes. Thanks for the advice, I'll apply it. I just have one question: why in the `build_default_discussion` is the variable `discussions` without an `@`?

Comment: For anyone interested in active record callback such as `before_create`, let's have a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe In this context `discussions` is a method that abstracts the attribute. Same as if you define `attr_accessor :name` in a Ruby class you can access that `name` attribute by calling the `name` method. You shouldn't attempt to access ActiveRecord attributes and associations by directly calling an instance variable, instead use the methods provided to you by ActiveRecord

Comment: @m.simonborg Is this even true from inside the class itself?

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe Absolutely! In Ruby there is a concept of `self` and methods can be called without an explicit receiver if they are being called on `self`. If it helps while you're learning to make it more explicit you can rephrase it to `self.discussions.build(title: 'Main Thread')`. The exception is *setter* methods, that *require* an explicit receiver to distinguish them from setting a local variable e.g. `self.discussions = [Discussion.new]` is calling the setter method, while `discussions = [Discussion.new]` would set a local variable called `discussions`.

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe you will find a lot of blog articles and SO questions to further your understanding if you google `ruby self`, `ruby implicit receiver` etc... A full explanation of scope in Ruby is a little too much for an SO comment thread : )